# Python: Changing values in classed dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say I have a classed dictionary in python, a file dict_ex.py containing e.g.

```
from dict_class import linear, quadratic
example_dict = { "ex1" : [linear(a=1.0,
                                 b=2.0)],
                 "ex2" : [quadratic(a=1.0,
                                   b=2.0,
                                   c=3.0)]
                 }
```

Where dict_class.py is a file defining the classes.

How can I use python to edit the dictionary values **within the file** dict_ex.py?

For clarity, I need a separate python program that I can run to modify the file containing the dictionary.

Python version is 3.9.18

I have tried using jsonpickle, but that would deal with the classes by turning them into an additional member of the dictionary entry, e.g.`"py/object" : "dict_class.linear"`

Comment: What is a "classed dictionary"?

Comment: May not be an official term, but in this example, linear and quadratic represent classes, so e.g. "ex1" is declared to be a member of the class "linear", with values a=1, b=2.

Comment: Where is the documentation of the `dict_class` library? It's not a standard python module.

Comment: It's probably either `example_dict['ex1'].a = 2.0` or `example_dict['ex1']['a'] = 2.0`

Comment: 'dict_class.py' is just a definition of the classes in question, what they are shouldn't be relevant.

As for your example, I need to write a code to edit the dictionary **within the file** 'dict_ex.py', not read it in and change the value there

Answer (score 1):

You could utilise the `ast` (Abstract Syntax Tree) module to parse the contents of the file into an AST, where we can walk through the AST and find exactly what we need to modify. In the code below, I'm using `astunparse`, a module that allows me to then unparse the ast into a string.

With respect to the structure and text of `dict_ex.py`:

```
import ast
import astunparse

def modify_dict_value(filename, key, new_value):
    # Read the dictionary from file
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()

    # Parse the code into an AST
    parsed = ast.parse(content)

    # Walk through the AST and find the dictionary
    for node in ast.walk(parsed):
        
        # "ast.Assign" is the node type for assignments (e.g. "a = 1", in this case, we're looking for the "example_dict" assignment")
        if isinstance(node, ast.Assign): 
          # node.targets is a list of targets, in this case, we're looking for the "example_dict" target (x=5, "x" is the "target")
          for target in node.targets:
              
              # "ast.Name" is the node type for names (e.g. "a" in "a = 1"), we're trying to find the "example_dict" name
              if isinstance(target, ast.Name) and target.id == 'example_dict':

                  # Loop through the keys and values of the dictionary we just found
                  for k, v in zip(node.value.keys, node.value.values):

                      # Check if the node is a string and if the string is the key we're looking to modify
                      if isinstance(k, ast.Str) and k.s == key:

                          # Modify the value of the dictionary, considering each key has a value that is a list, and each of these lists has only one item ("linear" or "quadratic") 
                          v.elts[0] = ast.parse(new_value).body[0].value
                          break

    # write the modified AST back into the source file, "astunparse" is used to convert the AST back into a string
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(astunparse.unparse(parsed))


# example usage
modify_dict_value('dict_ex.py', 'ex1', 'linear(a=5.0, b=6.0)')
```

**Please note:** in this case, we're assuming each key has a value that is a list, and each of these lists contains just one item ("linear" or "quadratic", in your case).